# Activitypub & Mastodon, how to get an Actor?

Tags: mastodon, activity-streams, activitypub

### The question

I'm currently trying to implement ActivityPub on my server to make it interoperate with mastodon.
I got stuck trying to retrieve an actor from another mastodon instance. The actor contains things like the inbox, outbox, and the public key for verifying requests signed by the actor.

It seams to get an actor, I need to send a signed get request. Although I know how to sign a request, I have a chicken egg problem, because the json-ld document representing the actor would contain the public key for verifying a request from that actor. Therefore, if I was to sign the request with my key, then the instance whose actor I'm trying to retrieve, in order to verify the key, would also have to retrieve my public key, and thus my actor. But if it did that, and I also check the signature, then I'd need to get that actor I tried to access in the first place to get the public key of it to do so.

How do I resolve this chicken egg situation? And why does mastodon not run into the same issue, do they do something differently?

### What I tried so far

I've made an account on some existing mastodon instance. I can look up the URL for the actor using webfinger:

```
curl https://awoo.space/.well-known/webfinger?resource=acct:DPA@awoo.space | jq
```

```
{
  "subject": "acct:DPA@awoo.space",
  "aliases": [
    "https://awoo.space/@DPA",
    "https://awoo.space/users/DPA"
  ],
  "links": [
    {
      "rel": "http://webfinger.net/rel/profile-page",
      "type": "text/html",
      "href": "https://awoo.space/@DPA"
    },
    {
      "rel": "self",
      "type": "application/activity+json",
      "href": "https://awoo.space/users/DPA"
    },
    {
      "rel": "http://ostatus.org/schema/1.0/subscribe",
      "template": "https://awoo.space/authorize_interaction?uri={uri}"
    }
  ]
}
```

So for that account, the actor url is `https://awoo.space/users/DPA`. But if I try to get the actor object:

```
curl -H 'Accept: application/ld+json; profile="https://www.w3.org/ns/activitystreams"' https://awoo.space/users/DPA
```

I get an error: 401, `Request not signed`.

To be honest, I do not understand why that request needs to be signed. It didn't seam to be the case for examples I found online, but in this case, for some reason it wants a signature, and I want to handle that properly.

Comment: I think this is related to mastodons ["secure mode"](https://docs.joinmastodon.org/spec/activitypub/#secure-mode). It says "Mastodon itself uses a dedicated system actor to sign such HTTP requests". But I couldn't find any more information about that yet.

Comment: Running into this as well, trying to debug. ActivityPub spec requires a POST, that's one thing. Reference on authentication/authorization in ActivityPub: https://www.w3.org/TR/activitypub/#authorization

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an odd, somewhat well-known ActivityPub quirk that's somehow a problem in theory but not in practice. The short answer is, sign your outbound AP requests with an actor from your own instance, any actor, and the remote instance will generally accept those signatures and respond happily, even if it hasn't seen your signing actor beforehand.

(I've had conversations in AP venues about this before, but I couldn't find them on https://socialhub.activitypub.rocks/ to cite, they may have been in chat instead.)

I suspect many AP implementations handle this with a [TOFU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trust_on_first_use) under the covers. Ie if a remote instance gets a `GET` signed by an unknown actor, it fetches that actor and only then starts verifying its signatures. This may happen synchronously on the first request (and block it), or in the background.

Also @Daniel Albrecht is right, this generally only matters with Mastodon (and some other) instances running in secure mode.

Answer (score 0):

The more canonical answer to this is evidently the "instance actor." Each instance can serve a special AP actor that represents the instance itself. Fetches for the instance actor do not require signatures, even if fetches for other actors and objects do. When an instance needs to make one of these chicken-and-egg external fetches that might require a signature, it can sign the fetch as its instance actor to break the loop.

More: https://seb.jambor.dev/posts/understanding-activitypub-part-4-threads/